# SES: Accessing email body inside lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm relatively new to AWS and I'm trying to process my email via Lambda Functions. I've built this one in node.js:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var http = require('http');
    var data = JSON.stringify(event);

    var options = {
        host: 'my.host',
        port: '80',
        path: '/my/path',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        var msg = '';

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            msg += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
        });
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
};
```

I've tested with the endpoint and it works perfectly, the problem is that I just now realized that the body of the message is never sent. How can I access the body of the message to send it and be processed by my api?

If you need to see a sample of whats sent let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So what I did was storing the email received in an S3 bucket, than notifying my api that a new email has arrived (sending the file name). Finally read from S3, parsed, stored and deleted from S3, inside my api.

**SES rules:**
[image: SES rules]

**Lambda notifying function:**

> Note that the name of the S3 file created by the first rule is the same as the messages id, hence `'fileName': event.Records[0].ses.mail.messageId`.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var http = require('http');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'fileName': event.Records[0].ses.mail.messageId,
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'my.host',
        port: '80',
        path: '/my/path',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        var msg = '';

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            msg += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
            context.succeed();
        });
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
};
```

**Api function (PHP - Laravel):**

> Note that I'm using an email parser that's based on Plancake Email Parser (link [here](https://github.com/daniele-occhipinti/php-email-parser)) with some changes of my own and if needed I'll edit to show the source.

```
public function process_incoming_email(Request $request)
{
    $current_time = Carbon::now()->setTimezone('Brazil/East'); // ALL TIMEZONES: http://us.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

    try
    {
        if ($request->has('fileName')
        {
            $file_name = $request->input('fileName');

            // GET CREDENTIALS AND AUTHENTICATE
            $credentials = CredentialProvider::env();
            $s3 = new S3Client([
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region'  => 'my-region',
                'credentials' => $credentials
            ]);

            // FECTH S3 OBJECT
            $object = $s3->GetObject(['Bucket' => 'my-bucket', 'Key' => $file_name]);
            $body = $object['Body']->getContents();

            // PARSE S3 OBJECT
            $parser = new EmailParser($body);
            $receivers = ['to' => $parser->getTo(), 'cc' => $parser->getCc()];
            $from = $parser->getFrom();
            $body_plain = $parser->getPlainBody();
            $body_html = $parser->getHTMLBody();
            $subject = $parser->getSubject();

            $error_message;

            // PROCESS EACH RECEIVER
            foreach ($receivers as $type => $type_receivers)
            {
                foreach ($type_receivers as $receiver)
                {
                    // PROCESS DOMAIN-MATCHING RECEIVERS
                    if(preg_match("/@(.*)/", $receiver['email'], $matches) && $matches[1] == self::HOST)
                    {
                        // INSERT NEW EMAIL
                        $inserted = DB::table('my-emails')->insert([
                            // ...
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // ADD ERROR LOG IF PARSER COULD NOT FIND EMAILS
            if($email_count == 0)
            {
                DB::table('my-logs')->insert(
                    ['sender' => $request->ip(), 'type' => 'error', 'content' => ($error_message = 'Could not parse received email or find a suitable user receiving email.') . ' File: ' . $file_name]
                );
            }
            // DELETE OBJECT FROM S3 IF INSERTED
            else if(count($emails) == $email_count)
            {
                $s3->deleteObject(['Bucket' => 'my-bucket', 'Key' => $file_name]);

                // RETURN SUCCESSFUL JSON RESPONSE
                return Response::json(['success' => true, 'receivedAt' => $current_time, 'message' => 'Email successfully received and processed.']);
            }
            // ADD ERROR LOG IF NOT INSERTED
            else
            {
                DB::table('my-logs')->insert(
                    ['sender' => $request->ip(), 'type' => 'error', 'content' => ($error_message = 'Inserted ' . count($emails) . ' out of ' . $email_count . ' parsed records.') . ' File: ' . $file_name]
                );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ERROR: NO fileName FIELD IN RESPONSE
            DB::table('my-logs')->insert(
                ['sender' => $request->ip(), 'type' => 'error', 'content' => ($error_message = 'Incorrect request input format.') . ' Input: ' . json_encode($request->all())]
            );
        }
    }
    // ERROR TREATMENT
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        DB::table('my-logs')->insert(
            ['sender' => $request->ip(), 'type' => 'error', 'content' => ($error_message = 'An exception occurred while processing an incoming email.') . ' Details: ' . $ex->getMessage()]
        );
    }

    // RETURN FAILURE JSON RESPONSE
    return Response::json(['success' => false, 'receivedAt' => $current_time, 'message' => $error_message]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for following up. Ran into the same issue. Seems a bit silly (not to mention inefficient) that we have to jump through so many loops to get at the message body. Is this still the same solution that you're using today?

Comment: @DaveJ Unfortunately yes :/

Comment: @MatheusSimon - I am trying to get something very similar to yourself running with laravel 5.4, Im using SES to accept all incoming emails and they are currently being stored in S3, My original thought was to parse them with a javascript function on Lambda and then send them over to laravel to store in DB and display in the application, Can i avoid lambda altogether with the email parser you have used by fetching the S3 object that SES stores? Appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: @Birdy no. what my lambda is doing is just telling my api that a new email has been received. notice that the body of the email is not being sent to my api, only its id. that was the workaround i found to do exactly what you want to do, because the only way for aws to converse with the api - consuming a web service - is through lambda functions. ps.: i've elaborated a little over this solution, if you want i can help you: mattzsimon at gmail dot com

Comment: @Birdy summary: cant consume web service without lambda, cant send body with lambda, so: email received, stored in s3, api notified with lambda, body fetched from s3 by api, parsed and stored, (optional: email deleted from s3). if this question helped please give it and its answer a thumbs up. thanks

Comment: I see what you say now mate, Would you be share your modified version of the email parser? I could give it a try this afternoon with a lambda function and hopefully get emails parsed, stored and passed to views :)

Comment: @Birdy yeah send me an email to the address i gave and ill be happy to send you the updated version

Comment: blem19@outlook.com - Look forward to speaking with you mate :) 2 heads are better than 1 :)

Answer (score 3):

I have a very similar solution to the other one, but with one fewer step. It is possible to set lambda triggers. So, I created a bucket `myemailbucket`, and sent the mail from SES to that bucket. Then I changed the trigger for my lambda function to any create event in s3 in the bucket `myemailbucket`.